# Errors after moving ASP.NET Identity classes to a Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am running into an issue after I copied over the identity classes and AccountController over to a ClassLibrary, I had to change some code around because of the async methods. Right now this is what I have in my AccountController

The original Register method looks like this

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, AccountNumber = model.AccountNumber };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

and I changed that method and it now looks like this

```
public void Register(RegisterAdministrator model)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email, AccountNumber = model.AccountNumber };
        var result = UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
    }
```

I am unfamiliar with async and await, so I thought it would be ok to remove it and I was wrong.

I am using JQuery Ajax to call a method in my controller and the method in the controller is this

```
[HttpPost]
public void AddNewAdministrator(NewAdministrator administrator)
    {
        #region Initialization

        OAD = new OQOEAdminstrationDAL();

        #endregion

        OAD.CreateNewAdministrator(administrator);
    }
```

The CreateNewAdministrator(administrator) is this

```
public void CreateNewAdministrator(NewAdministrator administrator)
    {
        #region Initialization

        RegisterAdministrator rva = new RegisterAdministrator();

        rva.UserName = administrator.administratorName;
        rva.Email = administrator.administratorEmail;
        rva.Password = administrator.administratorPassword;

        #endregion

        AccountController.Register(rva);
    }
```

Then the Register method is the one that I shown above and here it is again

```
public void Register(RegisterAdministrator model)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email, AccountNumber = model.AccountNumber };
        var result = UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
    }
```

Before I added the

> var result = UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

to this method, I would check the database and it wouldn't get populated with what I was passing from the

> var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email, AccountNumber = model.AccountNumber };

So I came to the conclusion that the table wouldn't get populated unless I had this in my method

> var result = UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

So I added it and when I step through the code, when I get to the var result an error gets thrown and here is the stacktrace of the error

```
System.IO.FileLoadException was unhandled by user code
```

HResult=-2146234304
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
  Source=AdvanceWareDAL
  FileName=Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
  FusionLog==== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/AdvanceWareRevision/AdvanceWareMVC/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\AdvanceWareRevision\AdvanceWareMVC\bin

## Calling assembly : AdvanceWareDAL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\AdvanceWareRevision\AdvanceWareMVC\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\Simon\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Simon/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/d8b6b64c/32bc7a85/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Simon/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/d8b6b64c/32bc7a85/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/AdvanceWareRevision/AdvanceWareMVC/bin/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Build Number
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.

StackTrace:
       at AdvanceWareDAL.Authentication.AccountController.get_UserManager()
       at AdvanceWareDAL.Authentication.AccountController.Register(RegisterAdministrator model) in c:\AdvanceWareRevision\AdvanceWareDAL\Authentication\AccountController.cs:line 201
       at AdvanceWareDAL.OQOEAdminstrationDAL.CreateNewAdministrator(NewAdministrator administrator) in c:\AdvanceWareRevision\AdvanceWareDAL\OQOEAdminstrationDAL.cs:line 45
       at AdvanceWareMVC.Controllers.AdministrationController.AddNewAdministrator(NewAdministrator administrator) in c:\AdvanceWareRevision\AdvanceWareMVC\Controllers\AdministrationController.cs:line 45
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
  InnerException:

The reason why I added the Identity classes and AccountController to the ClassLibrary is because I wanted to keep it separated from the main project, and made teh assumption that doing this would be easier than "hand rolling" the code than it would be to do this.

I am thinking that if I was able to add an App_Start folder and a config file in the ClassLibrary that I could load what the stack trace is looking for, from what I have read the ClassLibrary doesn't work like that.
I could just write my own method to populate the AspNetUsers table but then that would defeat the purpose of using the Identity classes.

So I am kind of stuck on how to fix all this so I can utilize the Identity framework from my ClassLibrary.

Comment: You are using Async methods, you have to use `await` or you have to `.Wait()` the result. Right now your "result" holds a task, not the result of the method call, and until its awaited (or run) the user is never logged in or registered. I'd suggest changing it back to the template that the original code had and pick up a book on async/await.

Comment: @RonBeyer, I think you are right. I don't understand enough of async/await. I thought everything would work somewhat the same when moving everything over.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are using Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, which is that enables OWIN-based applications to run on IIS using the ASP.NET request pipeline **and this will not work from a class library**.

Make sure you are not moving the OWIN Authentication manager along with your code. you can move the storage-related classes and code to the class library and keep the authentication pipeline in your web application.

[This](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity) article explain the ASP.NET Identity storage providers which in your case can be moved to your class library,,,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve your problem, but it might help.
As it occurs to me, this is a problem caused by the references used by .NET.
Try to load them again and rebuild. If the error persists, then try to locate and load the references used in your previous project. Let me know if this helped you :)

Comment: I tried what you mentioned and still getting the same error, I looked through my references from the main project and the classlibrary and all the same.

Comment: Have you tried re-adding the references from the old file to your new one ? Or just checked their version to look alike ?

Comment: I looked at the references and made sure that I had the same references from the main project to the classlibrary. I opened nuget and updated the class library packages.